# Spacing and custom x-axis ticks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to coerce space and ticks on my x-axis. I have the following data

> df

```
       Antibiotic timepoint resistant intermediate susceptible
1    Erythromycin0        T0 20.588235    79.411765     0.00000
2    Erythromycin1        T1 32.352941    67.647059     0.00000
3     Doxycycline0        T0  0.000000     0.000000   100.00000
4     Doxycycline1        T1  2.941176     0.000000    97.05882
5     Clindamycin0        T0  2.941176     5.882353    91.17647
6     Clindamycin1        T1 11.764706     5.882353    82.35294
7      Gentamycin0        T0  5.882353     5.882353    88.23529
8      Gentamycin1        T1 17.647059    11.764706    70.58824
9  Clarithromycin0        T0 17.647059    14.705882    67.64706
10 Clarithromycin1        T1 26.470588    23.529412    50.00000
```

when I us the geom_bar function I get the following graph

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill= variable, y=value, x=Antibiotic,  pattern = timepoint)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern(position="fill", stat="identity",
                   color = "black", 
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6)+
       scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0066CC","#FFFFFF","#FF8C00")) +
       theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
       scale_pattern_manual(values = c(T0 = "none", T1="stripe")) +
    guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))
```

[image]

I would like to increase the space between 2nd and 3rd bar, 4th and 5th bar etc. And also remove the ticks and add custom ticks with labels between the 1st and 2nd bar etc. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing complicated things to the x-axis, have you considered facetting your data? From reading your question, this accomplishes a very similar thing.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

txt <- "Antibiotic timepoint resistant intermediate susceptible
1    Erythromycin0        T0 20.588235    79.411765     0.00000
2    Erythromycin1        T1 32.352941    67.647059     0.00000
3     Doxycycline0        T0  0.000000     0.000000   100.00000
4     Doxycycline1        T1  2.941176     0.000000    97.05882
5     Clindamycin0        T0  2.941176     5.882353    91.17647
6     Clindamycin1        T1 11.764706     5.882353    82.35294
7      Gentamycin0        T0  5.882353     5.882353    88.23529
8      Gentamycin1        T1 17.647059    11.764706    70.58824
9  Clarithromycin0        T0 17.647059    14.705882    67.64706
10 Clarithromycin1        T1 26.470588    23.529412    50.00000"

df <- read.table(text = txt)
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(3:5)
df$abiotic_name <- gsub("0|1", "", df$Antibiotic)

ggplot(df, aes(timepoint, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~ abiotic_name, switch = "x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Building on Teunbrand's exposition with faceting, here's a more complete worked example that shows how to fake the x axis more completely using custom annotations and theme elements:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpattern)

df %>% 
  mutate(Antibiotic = gsub("\\d", "", Antibiotic)) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(timepoint, value, fill = name, pattern = timepoint)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern(position="fill", 
                   stat="identity",
                   color = "black", 
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_angle = 45/4,
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ffabab","#fff5ba","#dbffd7"), 
                    name = "variable") +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(T0 = "none", T1="stripe")) +
  labs(x = "Antibiotic") +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none"))) +
  facet_grid(.~Antibiotic, switch = "x") +
  annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob(), xmin = 1.5, xmax = 1.5, 
                    ymin = -0.075, ymax = -0.05) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]